# Enter the selected item in the search bar in React.js

Tags: reactjs, api, searchbar

I have the following code:

```
function App() {
  const [countries,setCountries]= useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  

 //Take data from API with useEffect, async/await and try/catch
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v2/all');
        setCountries(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const filteredCountries = countries.filter((country) => 
    country.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );

  
 
 
  const handleSelect = (country) => { 
    setSearch(country.name);
  }

  

  

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <SearchBar onChange={(e)=> setSearch(e.target.value)}  />
        {
          <ul className="list">
            {search.length > 0 && filteredCountries.map((country) => (
              <li key={country.name} onClick={() => handleSelect(country)}>
                {country.name}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        } 
      </div>
      <div className="map-container">

      </div>
    
</>  
  )
}

export default App;
```

The result is this:
[List image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8M7h.jpg)

How can I select an item from the list, e.g. if I search for Ital, Italy appears and I would like to select it and have it appear in the search bar.

I would like to create a search bar to find a country and select it, it should appear in the search bar after being selected.

CodeSandBox Link: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/pierre1590/Population-Tracker/draft/gallant-gagarin?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMap%2FMap.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `value={search}` in your  `<SearchBar/>` component.

eg: `<SearchBar value={search} onChange={(e)=> setSearch(e.target.value)}  />`

Below is the full code (I've used a normal input tag in place of your SearchBar component)

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';


function App() {
  const [countries,setCountries]= useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  
  console.log(search)

 //Take data from API with useEffect, async/await and try/catch
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v2/all');
        setCountries(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const filteredCountries = countries.filter((country) => 
    country.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );

  
 
 
  const handleSelect = (country) => { 
    setSearch(country.name);
  }

  

  

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input value={search} onChange={(e)=> setSearch(e.target.value)}  />
        {
          <ul className="list">
            {search.length > 0 && filteredCountries.map((country) => (
              <li key={country.name} onClick={() => handleSelect(country)}>
                {country.name}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        } 
      </div>
      <div className="map-container">

      </div>
    
</>  
  )
}

export default App;
```

CodeSandBox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/enter-the-selected-item-in-the-search-bar-in-react-js-582rez?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What if I want to clear the list after selecting the country?

Comment: You need to create filteredCountries as a useState. I've updated the code in codesandbox link. You can check there :)

Comment: I'm not able to access the above codesandbox link.

Comment: I’ve update the link in the question.